# How does Apache Sling script resolving rules work?

Tags: java, aem, sling

I have page with name `tst` in content whose

`sling:resourceType = news-portal/pages/test`

page structure (under the `/apps`):

[image]

test has

`sling:resourceSuperType = news-portal/pages/news-repo-main-page`

in browser I type following URL:

```
http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/tst.selector.pdf.html
```

after this request I see content of `selector.jsp`

But I expected to see content of `selector.pdf.jsp`  because it has more suitable much according my opinion.

1. Can you explain how it works?
2. Is there URL which can show content of `selector.pdf.jsp` ?
3. Does the choice of content affects if test had  `sling:resourceType`
   instead of `sling:resourceSuperType` or together? (I try to test but
   don't see affection)

P.S.

I know that answer somewhere here:

[image]

But I have problems with understanding

**P.S.**

log resolving:

```
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/content/tst.selector.pdf.html
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_END{0,ResourceResolution} URI=/content/tst.selector.pdf.html resolves to Resource=JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/tst
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/content/tst', selectorString='selector.pdf', extension='html', suffix='null'
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/tst)}
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/tst)} Using servlet /libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/content/tst.selector.pdf.html handled by Servlet=/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Applying Requestfilters
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter
      0 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG RedirectFilter did not redirect (MobileUtil.isMobileResource() returns false)
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Applying Componentfilters
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_START{/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp#0}
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Including resource JcrNodeResource, type=news-portal/pages/test, superType=null, path=/content/tst/jcr:content (SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/content/tst/jcr:content', selectorString='selector.pdf', extension='html', suffix='null')
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=news-portal/pages/test, superType=null, path=/content/tst/jcr:content)}
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=news-portal/pages/test, superType=null, path=/content/tst/jcr:content)} Using servlet /apps/news-portal/pages/news-repo-main-page/selector.jsp
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Applying Includefilters
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
      1 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_START{/apps/news-portal/pages/news-repo-main-page/selector.jsp#1}
      2 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) LOG Found processor for post processing ProcessorConfiguration: {contentTypes=[text/html],order=-1, active=true, valid=true, processErrorResponse=true, pipeline=(generator=Config(type=htmlparser, config={}), transformers=(Config(type=linkchecker, config={}), Config(type=mobile, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@25c0b221), Config(type=mobiledebug, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@deea7e4), Config(type=contentsync, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@2f5070e1), serializer=Config(type=htmlwriter, config={}))}
      2 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_END{1,/apps/news-portal/pages/news-repo-main-page/selector.jsp#1}
      2 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_END{1,/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp#0}
      2 (2014-03-28 13:18:31) TIMER_END{2,Request Processing} Request Processing
```

### UPDATE

I noticed that if I create following structure and send request to

```
http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/tst.selector.pdf.html
```

[image]

I see content of `pdf.jsp`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Sling there are two things: content (stored under `/content`) and code (stored under `/apps`). Content contains only properties data. There should be no logic, no JSP (or any other code) and selector information under `/content`.

On the other hand, `/apps` subtree contains scripts used to render the content. Such scripts are usually called *components*. `sling:resourceType` property (set for a piece of *data*, under `/content`) is a link between content and component. This is the way how content may say "following component should be used to display me".

`sling:resourceSuperType` has a different function. It is a property set on the component resource (under `/apps`), used to mark that this component should inherit JSPs and from another one. This property allows to create component hierarchy.

According to link in the comment it is also possible to put `sling:resourceSuperType` in the data component under `/content`. In this case, we *force* the component referenced in `sling:resourceType` to inherit from component referenced in `sling:resourceSuperType`. I don't know any use-case for that, tough.

In your case, please try creating following structure:

- `/content/test`

  - `sling:resourceType` = `news-portal/pages/test`
- `/apps/news-portal/pages/test`

  - component main resource, no special properties
- `/apps/news-portal/pages/test/test.jsp`

  - main JSP file
- `/apps/news-portal/pages/test/selector.jsp`

  - JSP used for selector
- `/apps/news-portal/pages/test/selector/pdf.jsp`

  - selector + pdf extension

Comment: **properties data** What does it mean?

Comment: My question was about using **sling:resourceType** for components elements. this make sense ?

Comment: I read this link: https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/the_basics.html#Sling%2520Request%2520Processing   and I don't understand what is discussed in end of chapter **Locating the script**  in subTitle **For example:**

Comment: at this example **/y** has and **sling:resourceSuperType** and **sling:resourceType** What the sense make such?

Comment: **sling:resourceType** doesn't make sense on the component elements and won't work. Apparently, **sling:resourceSuperType** may be set on the data resource too, but I don't know any use case for doing that.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly?  in topic update you wrote about case if element under **/content** has  both: and **sling:resourceSuperType** and **sling:resourceType** but if element under the **/content** has only **sling:resourceSuperType** - it hasn't sense ?   Sorry - I understand very little of English

Comment: please reply. I really need it.

Comment: Yes, it made no sense to add only a `sling:resourceSuperType` property to the content resource.

Comment: _"sling:resourceSuperType has a different function. It is a property set on the component resource (under /apps), used to mark that this component should inherit JSPs and from another one. This property allows to create component hierarchy."_ Would the content of super type resource component be rendered in page when using the component which has `sling:resourceSuperType` property.